# How can we prevent the react-type-animation from animating the entire section towards left while using NextJs and Tailwind?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, next.js, tailwind-css

While making my header section I used react-type-animation to animate the intro text, I have made a grid and two column inside the grid `col-span-7` and `col-span-5` , where I am using `col-span-7` for my intro text and animating it using react-type-animation but I have noticed its when the text increases, it moves the entire colum towards left. I want it to just animate the text not the entire column.Here is my component:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { TypeAnimation } from 'react-type-animation';

function HeroSection() {
    return (
        <section >
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-12">
                <div className='col-span-7 place-self-center text-center sm:text-left'>
                    <h1 className='text-white mb-4 text-4xl sm:text-5xl lg:text-6xl font-extrabold '>
                        <span className='text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 to-pink-600 '>
                            Hello, I'm {" "}
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        <div className='w-300px'>
                            <TypeAnimation
                                sequence={[
                                    // Same substring at the start will only be typed out once, initially
                                    'Rafia Zafar',
                                    1000, // wait 1s before replacing "Mice" with "Hamsters"
                                    'Frontend Developer',
                                    1000,
                                    'UI/Ux Designer ',
                                    1000,
                                    'Researcher',
                                    1000
                                ]}
                                wrapper="span"
                                speed={50}
                                repeat={Infinity}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </h1>
                    <p className='text-[#ADB7BE] text-base sm:text-xl mb-6'>I am a Frontend Developer</p>

                    <div>
                        <button className='rounded-full w-full sm:w-fit px-6 py-3 mr-4 bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 hover:bg-slate-200 text-white'>Hire me</button>
                        <button className='rounded-full w-full sm:w-fit px-1 py-1 bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 hover:bg-slate-800 text-white  mt-3'>
                            <span className='block bg-[#121212] hover:bg-slate-800 rounded-full px-5 py-2'>
                                Download CV
                            </span>

                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-5 place-self-center mt-4 lg:mt-0">
                    <div className='rounded-full bg-[#181818] w-[250px] h-[250px] lg:w-[400px] lg:h-[400px] relative'>
                        <Image
                            src='/images/hero-image.png'
                            className='absolute transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2'
                            width={300}
                            height={300}
                            alt='hero image'
                        />

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </section>
    )
}

export default HeroSection
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried the following solutions:

1. I have tried giving the left column a width of 500px to see if the animation goes to the next line and not move the whole column towards the left but it didn't work.
2. Then I tried wrapping the span around the whole animation tag.
3. Tried to change the placement of  tag

None of the above worked.